# How would I add data to a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I would like my user to be able to enter 4 fields that would allow them to populate a JTable. I have a JPanel in `CreateFxitures` class. On this JPanel they are able to enter data into two ComboBoxes and 2 TextFields. Once this data is all entered they should click `Create` Button, which will add all of the data into the `rowNames` array that is entered into the table. However when they click `Create` the row creates a new row, but doesn't add the data. how would i go about doing this?

MAIN Class:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;

public class Main 
{

    public Main()
    {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame ("AQA Computer Science Application");

        final CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel container = new JPanel(c1);

        Home homeCall = new Home();
        GuestFixtures guestCall = new GuestFixtures();
        final Login loginCall = new Login();
        final AdminFixtures adminCall = new AdminFixtures();
        final CreateFixtures createCall = new CreateFixtures();

        container.add(homeCall, "1");
        container.add(guestCall, "2");
        container.add(loginCall, "3");
        container.add(adminCall, "4");
        container.add(createCall, "5");
        createCall.createB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                if (createCall.descTF.getText().equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields must be entered");
                }else{
                    c1.show(container, "4");

                    adminCall.model.addRow(createCall.rowData);

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

CreateFixtures:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreateFixtures extends JPanel
{

    JButton backB, createB;
    JLabel typeL, descL, dateL, resultL;
    JComboBox typeCB, monthCB, dayCB;
    JTextField descTF, resultTF;
    String[] typeCBSTR = { "Football", "Tennis", "Swimming"};
    String[] monthCBSTR = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    String[] dayINT = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", };
    Object typeObject, monthObject;
    String typeSTR, descSTR, monthSTR, resultSTR;
    protected Vector rowData;
    public CreateFixtures()
    {

        final AdminFixtures adminCall = new AdminFixtures();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel createC = new JPanel(new GridLayout(12, 4));
        typeL = new JLabel("Type of Sport");
        typeCB = new JComboBox(typeCBSTR);
        descL = new JLabel("Description");
        descTF = new JTextField();
        dateL = new JLabel("Date");
        monthCB = new JComboBox(monthCBSTR);
        dayCB = new JComboBox(dayINT);
        resultL = new JLabel("Result");
        resultTF = new JTextField("TBA");

        createC.add(typeL);
        createC.add(typeCB);
        createC.add(descL);
        createC.add(descTF);
        createC.add(dateL);
        createC.add(monthCB);
        createC.add(dayCB);
        createC.add(resultL);
        createC.add(resultTF);

        typeObject = typeCB.getSelectedItem();
        typeSTR = typeObject.toString();
        descSTR = descTF.getText();
        monthObject = monthCB.getSelectedItem();
        resultSTR = resultTF.getText();

        Object[] rowData = {typeSTR, descSTR, monthSTR, resultTF};

        JPanel createS = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        backB = new JButton("Back");
        createB = new JButton("Create");

        createS.add(backB);
        createS.add(createB);

        createC.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        createS.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        add(createC, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

}
```

AdminFixtures:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class AdminFixtures extends JPanel
{

    JButton backB, createFixturesB, deleteButton;
    JTable adminFixturesTable;
    String[] columnNames = {"Fixture", "Description", "Date", "Result"};
    String[][] rowNames = null;
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public AdminFixtures()
    {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel adminC = new JPanel();
        adminFixturesTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(rowNames, columnNames));
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(adminFixturesTable);
        model = (DefaultTableModel) adminFixturesTable.getModel();

        JPanel adminS = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        backB = new JButton("Back");
        createFixturesB = new JButton("New Fixture");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete Row");

        adminS.add(backB);
        adminS.add(createFixturesB);
        adminS.add(deleteButton);

        adminC.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        adminS.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(adminS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

}
```

Comment: You're design seems to be weirdly off. You add the listener to a component of the `CreateFixtures` from inside the `Main` class, whiled referencing a new `AdminFixtures` created in the `Main` class, to try and change the `AdminFixtures` that is in your `CreateFixtures`. That seems to be your problem. Work on the design of your program. Listeners for a class should be added in _that_ class

Comment: Basically, I have `MAIN` which contains the main JPanel and calls the other cards(Classes). Each class is a new JPanel using CardLayout which is called by `MAIN` when it wants to be displayed. It is not an issue regarding the Listeners as I have many other Listeners in `Main` and they have not caused any issues.

Comment: So is the button in `CreateFixtures` _supposed_ to add a row, not to _its_ `AdminFixtures` model, but to the `AdminFixtures` model you created int the `Main`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I didn't know I created a model in `Main`. Basically, the Listener in `Main` is supposed to add a new row to the model in Admin Fixtures and add the data from `CreateFxitures` into this row.

Comment: Basically, I have no idea how I add a new row to a JTable with Strings from a textfield, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the field values with `getText()`. Then create an Object array from the values. Then use the `addRow(array)` like you are doing. Your array you are currently trying to add, holds all null values. So you just need to get the current values of the text fields, *then* add the row with them. Forget about the `createCall.rowData`. It's doing nothing for you. Create a new `Object[]` each time you press the button.  Something like

```
String data1 = typeSTR.getText();
String data2 = descSTR.getText();
String data3 = monthSTR.getText();
String data4 = resultSTR.getText();
Object[] row = { data1, data2, data3, data4 };
model.addRow( row );
```